# Error while creating a saveAS function in Python due to [Errno 22]

Tags: python, tkinter, errno

I'm creating a simple text editor in Python using tkinter.
When I try to create a SaveAs function I get this error:

```
File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\Parcial II - Compiladores\NotePad_DS.py", line 65, in save_file
file = open(file, 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\n'
```

This is my code:

```
def save_file(): 
    global text_field
    file = text_field.get(1.0, END)
    if file == '':
        file = None
    else:
#This is the line 65 where the editor says there is an error----
        file = open(file, 'w') 
#-------
        file.write(text_field.get(1.0, END))
        file.close()
    if file is None:
        file = fd.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension='.txt',
                                    filetypes=[("Text File", "*.txt*"), ("Word Document", '*,docx*'), ("PDF", "*.pdf*")])
    else:
        file = open(file, 'w')
        file.write(text_field.get(1.0, END))
        file.close()
        root.title(f"{os.path.basename(file)} - NotepadDS")
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what is in `file`? Are you aware it has a newline in it or is only a newline?

Comment: Why are you using the same text field for the filename and what you want to write to the file?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `global text_field`. You never assign the variable, you only read it.

Comment: `os.path.basename(file)` won't work. `file` is a file stream, not the filename, because you did `file = open(file, 'w')`. Don't reuse the same variable like that.

Comment: I changed some variable names, it worked ty